# This selection isn't valid. Make sure the copy and paste areas don't overlap

Tags: excel, vba

Keep getting error mentioned in the title on the "insert" line of code.  Both the cut and insert lines of code appear to be the same size.  I've been staring at this thing for hours.  I can't figure out where I'm messing up.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'convert communites by status

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H1:H1000")) Is Nothing Then
If Cells(Target.Row, 8) = "Takedown" Then
Range(Target.EntireRow, Target.Offset(13, 0).EntireRow).Cut
Sheets("AIKEN.AUGUSTA-TAKEDOWN").Range(Range("A12").EntireRow, 
 Range("A25").EntireRow).Insert
 Range("B12:B25").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Range("C13").Select

End If
End If

End Sub
```

expected result:  row range is cut from one part of the sheet and inserted in a different area of the sheet.

Actual result:  error on insert line of code.

Comment: So the change event handler is in sheet "AIKEN.AUGUSTA-TAKEDOWN" ?  So if I put "Takedown" in (eg) H12 it will cut from there but then insert it in the same place?

Comment: There's a data validation cell with a selected list and if you select "Takedown", the rows will be cut and moved to another section of the same sheet.  The problem is the Sheets("AIKEN...).Insert line.  It keeps throwing out the error.  I've removed "insert" and replaced it with "select" and there's no error.  I don't know why the "Insert" command is so problematic.

Comment: "moved to another section of the same sheet" - but if I enter Takedown on (eg) H12 isn't it going to cut the data and try and paste it back in the same place?

Comment: The "Takedown" section is at the top of the sheet and the other is at the bottom.  The rows are intended to be cut and inserted at the top of the list.  I know it's rudimentary.  The Range(Target.Offset...)) line is dynamic but since it will always insert the cells at the top of the list, I used absolute references.  So in this case, the data validation cell is on row 80 and I need it cut 14 rows which constitute a grouping of information and move it to the top of the sheet beginning on row 12.

Comment: OK I was looking at the H1:H1000 and assuming your code applied to the whole of that...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H26:H1000"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then            
        If Cells(rng.Row, 8) = "Takedown" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False '<< don't re-trigger on Cut
            Range(rng.EntireRow, rng.Offset(13, 0).EntireRow).Cut
            Me.Range("A12:A25").EntireRow.Insert
            Application.EnableEvents = True  '<< re-enable events
            Me.Range("B12:B25").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Me.Range("C13").Select
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```